# expr. tree: Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance

Tags: vb.net, linq, expression-trees

I searched the questions and found some topics and I suspect the error cause, but I can't figure it out.

I would like to build this expression part:

```
Function(row) groupedindexes.Select(
    Function(grpindex) row(grpindex))
```

I already build the part `Function(grpindex) row(grpindex)` with this:

```
Dim fieldselector As Expressions.LambdaExpression
fieldselector = Expression.Lambda(Expression.ArrayAccess(rowParameter, indexParameter), indexParameter)
```

The declarations are:

```
Dim rowParameter = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Object()), "Row")
Dim indexParameter = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Integer), "grpindex")
```

Now, I would like to build the `Select` part like this:

```
Dim outerfieldselector As Expressions.LambdaExpression
outerfieldselector = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Call(grpindexes, selectMethod, fieldselector), rowParameter)
```

The declarations are:

```
Dim grpindexes As Expression = Expression.Constant(groupedindexes, GetType(System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)))
Dim selectMethod = GetType(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static).First(Function(m) m.Name = "Select").MakeGenericMethod(GetType(Object), GetType(System.Func(Of Integer, Object)))
```

`groupedindexes` is a normal `List(Of Integer)`.

In runtime, I get the above error at the line `outerfieldselector=...`

In my opinion, it should work. I call the `Select` method on `grpindexes` with one argument (`fieldselector`).

What could be the problem?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: a sample project can be downloaded at this link: http://www.filedropper.com/exptree

**EDIT II:**

here a simple, short console application project:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Linq.Expressions
Module Module1
    Dim rowParameter = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Object()), "Row")
    Dim indexParameter = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Integer), "grpindex")
    Dim expr As Expression = Nothing
    Dim groupedindexes As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim grpindexes As Expression = Expression.Constant(groupedindexes, GetType(System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)))
    Dim selectMethod = GetType(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static).First(
        Function(m) m.Name = "Select").MakeGenericMethod(GetType(Object), GetType(System.Func(Of Integer, Object)))
    Dim fieldselector As Expressions.LambdaExpression
    Dim outerfieldselector As Expressions.LambdaExpression

    Sub Main()
        groupedindexes.Add(0)
        groupedindexes.Add(1)
        groupedindexes.Add(2)
        fieldselector = Expression.Lambda(Expression.ArrayAccess(rowParameter, indexParameter), indexParameter)
        outerfieldselector = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Call(grpindexes, selectMethod, fieldselector), rowParameter)
    End Sub
End Module
```

**EDIT 3:**

I think, I got it with the help of svick.

```
Dim selectMethod = GetType(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static).First(Function(m) m.Name = "Select").MakeGenericMethod(GetType(Integer), GetType(Object))
```

Comment: What is `grpindexes`? It would be easier to help you if you'd provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. (Just a minimal console app.)

Comment: I have added a simple project, because to copy all the code here would be too long. grpindexes represents the groupedindexes in the LINQ query.

Comment: It doesn't have to be your actual code. Just a short but representative program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: This is a sample small project. It is too mach connected to each other, therefore I uploaded it. It is exactly what you described: a short but representative program demonstraging the problem. Or uploads are here not allowed? Just run the project and hit the button.

Comment: It would be much better if you could make it short enough to include in your post. And if you have a button, that suggests it's a GUI - which is almost certainly adding pointless code. Console apps tend to be the simplest way of demonstrating problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `Queryable.Select()` is not an instance method. You call it as if it was one in VB, but it's not, and that's reflected in expression trees.

So, the line should look like this:

```
outerfieldselector = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Call(Nothing, selectMethod, grpindexes, fieldselector), rowParameter)
```

Even if you fix that, your code still won't work. Some of the issues are:

1. `MakeGenericMethod()` expects the types of the type parameters. Here those are `TSource` and `TResult`, which should be `Integer` and `Object`.
2. `List(Of Integer)` does not implement `IQueryable`.

Comment: And how should I modify the code? I changed the types in the MakeGenericMethod, but I get an error. Even if List(Of Integer) does not implement IQueryable, it is possible to call Select, because in a LINQ query, it is possible.

Comment: I changed the types in the MakeGenericMethod and changed the Queryable to Enumerable.

Comment: @derstauner Yeah, LINQ on normal collections works because they implement `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IQueryable<T>`, which means you want `Enumerable.Select()`, not `Queryable.Select()`.